# How to place Row elements' centers evenly (not using Expanded-s)

Tags: flutter, dart, layout, row

I tried my best to summarize what I want in the title, but here is a more detailed explanation:

- Widgets' centers should be placed evenly throughout the row.
- A larger widget should be able to extend into the "personal space" of a smaller one.
- When it would overflow, overflow should start on the bigger items, cutting into the smaller ones later.

### Here's an illustration:

#### [Behavior with `Expanded`s:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpaSi.png)

1. Everything fits
2. Longest item is overflowing - **The problem with this is that the longest text would easily fit if it could extend into the boundary of the shorter texts next to it.**

#### [How it should work:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAXPq.png)

**Please notice:** The boxes are not `Expanded`, but the **centers of them** are evenly placed (not by themselves, but as if they were the centers of `Expanded`s). As opposed to just laying them out with usual `MainAxisAlignment` options; neither of those ensures that the centers are evenly placed, a longer text can push the shorter ones to one side. [(Illustraion of what I **don't** want)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANxco.png)

1. Everything fits
2. Longest text extends into the area of the shorter ones
3. When two boxes would touch, overflow the longer one
4. Extreme case - default to even sizes

This may be asking a lot, but I think there should be a way of achieving these, what's more, I think this should be the default way rows with texts work.
Any help on any sub-request is much appreciated.

*Edit:* I understand that everything I described is pretty complicated when put together. I would be happy to know a way to just simply place center lines evenly, with different width boxes (and no, `spaceEvenly` doesn't do this). Overflowing behavior can be a different question.

Comment: *"what's more, I think this should be the default way rows with texts work.*" - i dont think that ordinary `Row` (or similar stuff) can do that, most likely you need a custom [MultiChildRenderObjectWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MultiChildRenderObjectWidget-class.html)

Comment: Yeah I figured, it wouldn't be simple... Can you suggest where to look further, what properties I could use?

Comment: imho you need to write a custom `Widget` - the one which extends `MultiChildRenderObjectWidget`

Comment: Can you maybe link some material on `MultiChildRenderObjectWidget`s and how to even begin understanding them (if it exists)? The API docs is pretty sparse on the matter.

Comment: Thanks for your time in these answers, I will look into this issue further later! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly`? Then you can play with the padding. It seems that you would also like to make your UI responsive, try the `LayoutBuilder` class. The documentation can be found here https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/responsive .

Comment: `spaceEvenly` doesn't place center lines evenly. It does what I illustrated here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANxco.png
However, this `LayoutBuilder` sounds promising, can you suggest what functions of it I could make use of in this situation? Simply knowing how big the boxes will be doesn't help much.

Comment: Hmmm, try the `Align` function. An example can be found here: https://mrflutter.com/how-to-align-widgets-in-flutter-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

First of all use 3 `Expanded()` for taking spaces for 3 `Text()` `Widgets` after that you can align your text at center using a container. Hope this solution will meet your requirement.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text('Lorem', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text('Lorem ispum', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text('Lorem', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),),
          ),
        ),
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I wrote up what your're suggesting [in DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/b6409e10de32b280b8938aa75364fa7b?) quick, it doesn't space center lines evenly. It does this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANxco.png

Comment: it gives evenly space between widget rather than for every widget. so now what you want exactly? please let me know.

Comment: I'd like the center lines to be distributed as if they were the center lines of expandeds, but in a way they don't necessarily limit their children to the 1/3-rd space, and they can extend out into the space of the neighboring widgets as long as they don't touch. I tried to illustrate this in my original post.

Comment: I updated my answer. I hope it will work. thank you. @RedyAu